# COGNOS Report Studio : Make a certain query run before any other queries

Tags: sql-server, performance, cognos

Is there any way in **COGNOS Report Studio** by which I can make my query run first before any other queries ?

**Use Case:** I have a COGNOS report which compares the results of 7-8 stored procedures(sps) to find out data discrepancies. For this I have to join results of sps A with results of sp B, B with C ,A with D and so on. As COGNOS has no caching of results(local caching is not useful) and is slow in executing stored procedures, I have implemented a pseudo caching technique. At the beginning of the report generation, I store the results of 3-4 time consuming sps into tables. And in the COGNOS queries where I want the data for comparison I simply do a `SELECT *` on the tables. The **problem** is how to ensure that this cache generation query runs first, so that I dont run into a situation where another query is doing a SELECT * before data population.

**Inelegant Solution:** Have a dummy prompt which gets auto submitted after the actual prompt. And make the cache generation query as the source query for the dummy/invisible prompt. So this way after the user selects value in the prompt, another prompt comes up, which gets auto submitted and thus the cache generation query runs before any other query.

P.S.

1. The reason cognos is used for this is that, the sps in question are actually sources for other COGNOS reports, so by comparing the sps I am actually comparing different reports, and the business wants to see the discrepancy report in PDF only.
2. Using the pseudo caching technique as mentioned above,  I have reduced run time of report from 50 min to 30 min. The problem with this solution is that when the report is run with option 'Send report by mail', sometimes it gets timed out, and no mail is received.

Please let me know if there is any other way of running a COGNOS query first before other queries and if possible, please suggest some ways to improve performance.

**Platform** SQL server and COGNOS report studio

Comment: Didn't read the whole question, but why on earth are you doing this in cognos at all? This is a job for your trusted database administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Doesnt seem like a good case for a "live" report. I would utilize a SQL scheduler to run your SPs beforehand and write the last completed date to a debug table. Have Cognos read off the tables you've created along with the last run date from the debug table.

Answer (score 0):

Possible wrap the whole thing in another stored procedure, having it do the comparisons and just return the results to Cognos?

Answer (score 0):

" As COGNOS has no caching of results.... and is slow in executing stored procedures"

No slower than if you run them directly. I agree with all other comments. You could wrap them up in another stored procedure but I actually recommend you take a step back and do some proper performance tuning (i.e. indexes and query plans)

Answer (score 0):

Agree with all comments above.

You can use a Cognos Cognos Job to run an stored procedure to pre-fill your “disrepancy” report table and then run Cognos Report just on that table and email it out in one go. And I'm not sure what your data volumes are, but 30 minutes way to much for any reasonable report (unless you're trawling through GBs of data, but you should be doing that in ETL anyway).

As a general rule, I try to do all data checks during ETL execution and then trigger Event Studio agents in load jobs to email data wrong / missing / not loaded reports to people responsible for data quality.